# Understanding double for-in

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop

In some code I am modifying I have found the following

```
data = # np.array with shape (200, 300, 64, 64, 3)
data = np.array([item for obs in data for item in obs])
```

where `item` and `obs` haven't been defined. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the syntax of the double for-in line. How should I read this?

Comment: Write it out like a regular for loop and it should make sense.  `for obs in data: for item in obs: print(item)`.   The ordering can just be a bit confusing in a list comprehension.

Comment: It's a list comprehension, and `data` is an iterable of elements that are themselves iterables. Just read it as two nested `for` loops, nested in the same order.

Comment: @user3483203: I find the order to be entirely logical, it's nesting order from left to right. Add in `if` filtering and it becomes clearer still. What throws people at first is that the innermost loop expression is put before all the loops, but that initial confusion passes quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I don't entirely agree with the duplication mark, as it is different list comprehensions, but I get it now, thank you.